# Is there a way to detect screen manipulation apps from another app programmatically?

Tags: android, security

So I was using [Blockchain mobile wallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet/android-app) on my Android device and I had my blue light filter app on, when I opened the wallet app I got a warning that says "There is a screen recording/manipulating app" running on this device.

I'd like to have this feature in my app, is there a way to detect those kind of apps?

It's possible to block Screen shots with [Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

But is it possible to detect recording or filtering? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544931/how-to-programmatically-detect-if-any-screen-recording-process-app-is-running-in) is somewhat similar but the answer is not reliable at all, since there is an app with this feature.

Comment: May be this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25178500/150978

Comment: Did you finally find out? Would be interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **FLAG_SECURE** for prevent screen recording.

Example

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```